# What can cause automatically removing my Java and several librarys like C++boost?

Tags: dpkg

I'm working with a project using libboost. Early this morning out of nowhere I wasn't able to compile it anymore. It was noting that boost/version.hpp could not be found. I was trying out quiet a lot of stuff but it made no sense to me. I also wasn't able to figure out where my libboost files had been located and everything was hinting I never had it installed, but I was using it now already for months. Now I just checked dpkg.log and found this entries, like 5 minutes after my last successful build:

```
2017-10-13 08:19:26 remove libboost-iostreams-dev:amd64 1.58.0.1ubuntu1 <none>
2017-10-13 08:19:26 status half-configured libboost-iostreams-dev:amd64 1.58.0.1ubuntu1
2017-10-13 08:19:26 status half-installed libboost-iostreams-dev:amd64 1.58.0.1ubuntu1
2017-10-13 08:19:26 status config-files libboost-iostreams-dev:amd64 1.58.0.1ubuntu1
2017-10-13 08:19:26 status config-files libboost-iostreams-dev:amd64 1.58.0.1ubuntu1
2017-10-13 08:19:26 status config-files libboost-iostreams-dev:amd64 1.58.0.1ubuntu1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status not-installed libboost-iostreams-dev:amd64 <none>
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status installed libboost-iostreams1.58-dev:amd64 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 remove libboost-iostreams1.58-dev:amd64 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 <none>
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status half-configured libboost-iostreams1.58-dev:amd64 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status half-installed libboost-iostreams1.58-dev:amd64 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status config-files libboost-iostreams1.58-dev:amd64 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status config-files libboost-iostreams1.58-dev:amd64 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status config-files libboost-iostreams1.58-dev:amd64 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status not-installed libboost-iostreams1.58-dev:amd64 <none>
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status installed libboost-regex-dev:amd64 1.58.0.1ubuntu1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 remove libboost-regex-dev:amd64 1.58.0.1ubuntu1 <none>
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status half-configured libboost-regex-dev:amd64 1.58.0.1ubuntu1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status half-installed libboost-regex-dev:amd64 1.58.0.1ubuntu1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status config-files libboost-regex-dev:amd64 1.58.0.1ubuntu1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status config-files libboost-regex-dev:amd64 1.58.0.1ubuntu1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status config-files libboost-regex-dev:amd64 1.58.0.1ubuntu1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status not-installed libboost-regex-dev:amd64 <none>
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status installed libboost-regex1.58-dev:amd64 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 remove libboost-regex1.58-dev:amd64 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 <none>
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status half-configured libboost-regex1.58-dev:amd64 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status half-installed libboost-regex1.58-dev:amd64 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status config-files libboost-regex1.58-dev:amd64 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status config-files libboost-regex1.58-dev:amd64 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status config-files libboost-regex1.58-dev:amd64 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status not-installed libboost-regex1.58-dev:amd64 <none>
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status installed libicu-dev:amd64 55.1-7ubuntu0.2
2017-10-13 08:19:27 remove libicu-dev:amd64 55.1-7ubuntu0.2 <none>
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status half-configured libicu-dev:amd64 55.1-7ubuntu0.2
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status half-installed libicu-dev:amd64 55.1-7ubuntu0.2
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status config-files libicu-dev:amd64 55.1-7ubuntu0.2
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status config-files libicu-dev:amd64 55.1-7ubuntu0.2
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status config-files libicu-dev:amd64 55.1-7ubuntu0.2
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status not-installed libicu-dev:amd64 <none>
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status installed icu-devtools:amd64 55.1-7ubuntu0.2
2017-10-13 08:19:27 remove icu-devtools:amd64 55.1-7ubuntu0.2 <none>
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status half-configured icu-devtools:amd64 55.1-7ubuntu0.2
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status half-installed icu-devtools:amd64 55.1-7ubuntu0.2
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status config-files icu-devtools:amd64 55.1-7ubuntu0.2
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status config-files icu-devtools:amd64 55.1-7ubuntu0.2
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status config-files icu-devtools:amd64 55.1-7ubuntu0.2
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status not-installed icu-devtools:amd64 <none>
2017-10-13 08:19:27 status installed libboost-atomic-dev:amd64 1.58.0.1ubuntu1
2017-10-13 08:19:27 remove libboost-atomic-dev:amd64 1.58.0.1ubuntu1 <none>
```

This is continuing with quiet a lot other libs where at least a handful I know of and know them being important.

I myself with my active user wouldn't have been able to even remove them.
So it actually AFAIK must have been a privileged removal without my consents. What feature/program could have caused this? And how could I figure that out precisely?

Comment: Anything related in `/var/log/apt/history.log`?

Comment: @muru: for that same time 2 entrys, "Start-Date: 2017-10-13  08:19:15
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: xserver-common:amd64[...]" and "Start-Date: 2017-10-13  08:19:26
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Remove:  [over 100 librarys]"

Comment: looks like it has also been tried to remove my linux headers.

Comment: It probably ran `apt-get autoremove` and anything that wasn't manually installed or a dependency of something manually installed got removed.

Comment: Any way to figure out what it was and how this could happen? I mean, this probably fucked my whole system up v.v

Comment: It says `unattended-upgrade`, doesn't it? http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/unattended-upgrade.8.html

Comment: @muru: yep it does. I'm checking the logs there. But actually it just removed everything I DID manually install. Everything. ranging from tomcat over java to specific manually installed c librarys. Thats very strange --> looks like an programm called "libmir" was updatted and in that process everything else ahd been removed...

Comment: @muru: I figured out so far, unattended-upgrade issued the upgrade/(installation?) of 2 programms. After that it immediately removed all the other libs. so nothing that got removed and could even issue the dependending removal of other apps. If no one has an idea how this could have been caused, anyway to prevent that ever happening again?